# What is C in Standard Form derived from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For Example $9x + 16y = 72$. What is $72$ derived from? Why does dividing $72$ by $9x$ get us to the slope? Why does dividing $72$ by $16y$ get us to the $y$ intercept?

Comment: What do you mean "derived from"?  You wrote it down...

Comment: I'm doing an exercise. I would like to know what 72 is based on and why dividing by that number makes sense. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Do you mean: given an equation for a line, such as $y=mx+d$, how can you get the equation to have the form $ax+by=c$?

Comment: $72$ means that the line intersects the $x-axis$ at $x=72/16$.

Comment: Well in simple terms, what I mean is that if you take the equation in standard form, to convert it to slope intercept form, all it takes is solving the algebraic equation. Why does that make sense and where is the number 72 derived from. Hope you understand.

Comment: You asked earlier about the books by Blitzer; here are places to buy the sixth edition, one in England. https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?isbn=9780134469171&cm_sp=mbc-_-9780134469171-_-all  I am guessing you prefer English to German; however, there are surely similar books in German, and ABEBOOKS might easily have a version in Germany (I have purchased books that came from shops in Germany, through this site)

Comment: Thanks Jaggy, do you know why this one (loose leaf edition) only contains ~500 pages** and the 250$ edition over 1000?

Comment: No way of knowing; first, let me point out https://www.abebooks.de/   then I will check. Note that Blitzer has many editions, also a solutions manual, also a set of DVD's which are probably like the Khan academy except they are him giving lessons about this book (I think). Let me check that last part. Anyway, let me try to find out about your 500 and 1000 pages

Comment: here is the german site on Blitzer, many results, shipping assumed to be going to Germany: https://www.abebooks.de/servlet/SearchResults?sts=t&an=blitzer&tn=algebra+and+trigonometry&kn=&isbn=

Comment: To those voting to close/downvoting (I accidentally closed so I'm casting a reopen vote), this is a valid question IMO, and I believe it's best to approach this from the elementary perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard form" of a line is $Ax + By = C$ where $A$ and $B$ are not all zero. Usually we write lines in the slope intercept form $y = mx +b$. Here's how to go from standard form to slope-intercept form - I show all my students this.

From the standard form, divide by $B$ to allow the coefficient of $y$ to be $1$.

$$ \frac{A}{B}x + y = \frac{C}{B} $$

Now let's subtract $\frac{A}{B}x$ on both sides.

$$y = -\frac{A}{B}x + \frac{C}{B} $$

Now we do a thing called "equating coefficients." This process allows us to identify the slope and y-intercept of this line. The coefficient on $x$ is the slope, and the constant term the y-intercept. Hence we may identify $ m = -\frac{A}{B}$ and $b = \frac{C}{B}$.

Of course, you ask about $C$ in particular.  This is a parameter to help define other pieces of the line - namely, intercepts. Changing $C$ changes the location of these intercepts.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I might have phrased the question wrong.. but I tried to understand how they make an equation like this. Like how does Khan Academy come up with 9x + 16y = 72. Where did they take 9x, 16y and 72 from and what is the meaning of 72 itself (C). It sucks but we don't have German speaking forums so I just try to explain it in the best possible way that my English speaking abilities allow me to.

Comment: @EliS.: Can you refer us to the Khan link so we can now better what you are referring to?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/two-var-linear-equations/standard-form/v/standard-form-for-linear-equations

Comment: @Eli It's just for the sake of exercise. In fact, you should know that two distinct points determine a line, so given the intercepts, one can describe a line by an equation those intercepts satisfy. The $C$ comes from possibly clearing fractions and making things a little more manageable. Not everything has a reason - I hate to give the "that's the way it is" cop-out, but, yeah.

Comment: @Sean Roberson Yeah I just like to dig into the why's, should probably let that go.